# Less css nesting?

Tags: css, less, mixins, nested

I have some issues with nesting in Less, here is my less

```
.edit-qa-table {
    thead {

        tr {
            th:first-child + th {
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        tbody {

            tr {
                th:first-child + th {
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }
        }

        .thead-append {
            th:first-child {
                width: 45%;
            }
            &:first-child + th + th{
                min-width:130px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All working fine, but i have more two rules to add, but i have tried but no luck, only way is to make them seperate, but i dont want that, i want nest this two rules inside one

```
 .edit-qa-table > tbody > tr > td:first-child + td{
     text-align:center;
 }


.edit-qa-table{
    tbody{
        tr{
            td{
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This compiled CSS

```
.edit-qa-table thead tr th:first-child + th {
  text-align: center;
}
.edit-qa-table thead tbody tr th:first-child + th {
  text-align: center;
}
.edit-qa-table thead .thead-append th:first-child {
  width: 45%;
}
.edit-qa-table thead .thead-append:first-child + th + th {
  min-width: 130px;
}
.edit-qa-table > tbody > tr > td:first-child + td {
  text-align: center;
}
.edit-qa-table tbody tr td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But i need to put all those rules in just one mixing? form all my rules to make just one mixing rule

Comment: To my knowledge, [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JorMGP) is the most you can do in this case. Group the selectors wherever possible, use extend where it can be used etc. If you are OK with this, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Please add answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is the most (to my knowledge) that you could re-factor or reduce this code and make it part of the same nested structure.

Basically, all that I have done is group all selectors which have similar properties/rulesets and similar selector hierarchy together. For selectors where the properties/rulesets are same but the hierarchy is a bit different, we could use the `:extend` feature. The advantage is that when you make any change to the list of properties (or rulesets) used by the base, the list of properties assigned to the selector which is extending the base will also be updated and thereby avoid the need to overwrite in all places.

> Possible drawback is that in future if you want to assign different property list for them then you have to rework the structure. So, choose the grouping or use of extend accordingly.

```
.edit-qa-table{
    thead {
        tr, tbody tr{
            th:first-child + th{
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
        .thead-append{
            &:first-child{
                + th + th{
                    min-width: 130px;
                }
            }
            th:first-child{
                width: 45%;
            }
        }
    }
    tbody tr td{
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    > tbody > tr > td:first-child + td:extend(.edit-qa-table thead tr th:first-child + th){};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem, here the code the should solve your problem:

```
.edit-qa-table {
    thead {

        tr {
            th:first-child + th {
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        tbody {

            tr {
                th:first-child + th {
                    text-align: center;
                }

        td
        {
          vertical-align:middle;
        &:first-child + td{
     text-align:center;
 }
        }
            }
        }

        .thead-append {
            th:first-child {
                width: 45%;
            }
            &:first-child + th + th{
                min-width:130px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUPUT CSS:

```
.edit-qa-table thead tr th:first-child + th {
  text-align: center;
}
.edit-qa-table thead tbody tr th:first-child + th {
  text-align: center;
}
.edit-qa-table thead tbody tr td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.edit-qa-table thead tbody tr td:first-child + td {
  text-align: center;
}
.edit-qa-table thead .thead-append th:first-child {
  width: 45%;
}
.edit-qa-table thead .thead-append:first-child + th + th {
  min-width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: Try to compile my css, you will se what you will get, your is not working

Comment: My will not work only because is missing `.table-edit` mixin declaration (same in yours too). To compile mine, I simply add an empty declaration for it, in order to ignore compile error `.table-edit{}`. Is this the problem that you have?

Comment: @play2web: Are you referring to the missing children (`>`) selectors in Luca's code?

Comment: @play2web: I removed mixin too. If Harry has reason.... it's not possible to unify declarations, because effectively they are different selectors, while apparently very similar